# Interesting Way to Write a Question

Tags: discussion, chat

I happen to be hanging around when an avid user from Stack Overflow, [viyancs](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/4363/viyancs), visited our site to post a question about a problem he was facing. His question was a little vague, and it was only about 15 minutes old, so I posted the following comment:

> Hi viyancs, I think first you need to identify the problem. Do you know *why* deadlines are being missed? Could you perhaps [edit] and tell us more about your team, like how many people, the project, how late it is, and what you might have tried before? Thanks! :)

Moments later, I noticed he edited the post and added more details. The edit message told me that the post had been edited "3 minutes ago", so I dropped another comment on the question:

> Feel free to [join our chat room on this topic](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management).

**The Chat Begins:**

A moment later, viyancs joined me, and we discussed the problem he was facing, which is one that I've been through personally as a former developer who became a PM.

We used our conversation in chat to edit his question and add more details to it, and I was also able to ask him some questions of my own and use that information to give him some advice based on my own personal experiences.

**The Results:**

At the end of our conversation, I left the following comment on the question:

> Here is a [chat transcript between jmort253 and viyancs](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5589368#5589368), which discusses this project management challenge. – jmort253♦

This was a cool, fun experiment that combined our [real time chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management) with writing questions on Project Management Stack Exchange, and I suggest that you try it as well to see if there are other hidden insights. Judge the results for yourself right here:

[What Should a Project Manager Do If Development is Not Completed On Time?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/what-should-a-project-manager-do-if-development-is-not-completed-on-time)

**So, how can we improve on this concept and use chat as a tool to refine questions and answers?**